# Framework7 : how change side panel width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, html-framework-7

I need to change the width of side panel in framework7 ??

https://framework7.io/docs/side-panels.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change css of class panel.

default value (in framework7.ios.css) :

```css
.panel {
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    background: #111;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    position: absolute;
    width: 260px;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-transition-duration: .4s;
    transition-duration: .4s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For search engine purposes, here's the right answer.  Put this in your custom scss file, changing width to what you want

**right panel**

```
.panel-right {
    --f7-panel-right-width: 360px;
    --f7-panel-width: 360px;
}
```

**left panel**

```
.panel-left {
    --f7-panel-left-width: 360px;
    --f7-panel-width: 360px;
}
```

Doing it this way will automatically change the transform css so that your animation remains smooth.